# How to assign a variable different values based on a column cell values

Tags: sql

I need to loop through all rows and do the following:

```
If the Date_Deleted is null then SET @Form = '01' else @Form = '02'
```

Currently is returning Form = 01 only.

Thank you!

```
SELECT @CHECKDATE = [DATE_DELETED] 
FROM Executive__Vehicles
WHERE (STATE = 'NC') 

IF ( @CHECKDATE is null )
    BEGIN
        SET @FORM = '01'        
    END
ELSE  
    BEGIN
        SET @FORM = '02'   
    END
```

Comment: your query seems to return more than one value if that's the case then `@Checkdate` will set based on the last row in your query result.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Glk.net thank you I was wondering if was the first or last row that set the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load all the results from Executive_vehicles into a temp table and then loop through them one by one to do the set.

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable1(iID int identity(1,1),date_deleted datetime)
INSERT INTO #tempTable1
select [DATE_DELETED]
FROM Executive__Vehicles WHERE (STATE = 'NC')

DECLARE @countROws int 
DECLARE @CHECKDATE datetime
DECLARE @topRow INT
SET @countRows =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempTable1)
WHILE @countRows>0
BEGIN
SET @topRow = (SELECT TOP 1 iID from #tempTable1)
SET @CHECKDATE = (SELECT TOP 1 date_deleted from #tempTable1)
 IF ( @CHECKDATE is null )
BEGIN SET @FORM = '01'
END

ELSE  
BEGIN
SET @FORM = '02'   
END 

DELETE FROM #tempTable1 where iID=@topRow
set @countRows = (SELECT count(*) FROM #tempTable1)
set @CHECKDATE  = NULL
END
```

editted to add identity column as date_deleted could be same for multiple rows and delete would delete all of them.

Comment: You made my day! I cannot begin to say THANK YOU!!!!!! It was hard to make sense of the stuff I found on the internet because they use while rows>0 start counting and then nothing which confused me. Now that I see that you start with the top row it makes sense. Once again thank you thank you thank you!